# ¿Por qué tengo un error al crear un dominio en MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

He intentado hacer un dominio en MariaDB, pero no me ha salido, siempre obtenía error de sintaxis; así que fuí a leer la documentación en

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/create-domain-statement/

Usando el código:

```
CREATE SCHEMA bob
  CREATE DOMAIN domain_1 AS SMALLINT;
```

Pero sigo obteniendo error de sintaxis:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE SCHEMA bob
-> CREATE DOMAIN domain_1 SMALLINT;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DOMAIN domain_1 SMALLINT' at line 2
```

Esta es la versión que tengo actualmente de MariaDB:

```
Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB
```

No consigo de ninguna manera crear un dominio.

Comment: Y qué pasa si después de bob pones un punto y coma, tal que ambas sentencias sean independientes?

Comment: @amenadiel En la documentación pone: The <Domain name> identifies the Domain and the Schema to which it belongs. A <Domain name> that includes an explicit <Schema name> qualifier belongs to the Schema named. A <Domain name> that does not include an explicit <Schema name> qualifier belongs to the SQL-session default Schema.  Eso es lo que intento que ese dominio pertenezca a este esquema en concreto.

Comment: @lois6b obtengo este error: 
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for 
    the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DOMAIN bob.domain_1 AS SMALLINT' at line 2

Answer (score 2):

Que yo sepa, ni MySQL, ni MariaDB tiene la capacidad de crear dominios.

El problema es que el enlace que incluistes como la ["documentación"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/create-domain-statement/) para MariaDb, en realidad no lo es.  Como bien dice en el recuadro arriba de la página, esa información tiene que ver con el estándar SQL-99, y no necesariamente significa que exista esa sintaxis en MariaDB.

El enlace que quieres para verificar la lista de comandos `CREATE` en MariaDB es la siguiente: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create/. Pero verás que no incluye ninguna sentencia para crear dominios.

Comment: Tiene todo el sentido, no me había percatado de ese dato! Mil gracias! Pero entonces qué debo usar para crear dominios?

Comment: cierto, pone: `" the contents of this and other pages in the book may not directly apply to MariaDB."`

Comment: @BigHelmet: Tendrías que usar otro motor de base de datos como PostgreSQL por ejemplo. MariaDB no tiene esa capacidad. Con MariaDB, debes limitarte a usar los tipos ya existentes. Si agregas mas detalles en cuanto a lo que necesitas, tal vez se te pueda sugerir una alternativa aceptable.

Comment: @sstan Muchas gracias! Bueno la verdad es que era para una asignatura de la uni, que nos dieron como recurso un libro de base de datos y al llegar a la parte de dominio, lo intente ejecutar en MariaDB, que ya lo tenía instalado. Probaré PostgreSQL, mil gracias